# Composer require drupal/social_auth_google - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: composer

Previously I got an error with the command

```
composer require "drupal/social_auth_google:^2.0"
```

So I tried;

```
composer require "drupal/social_api:2.x-dev" "drupal/social_auth:2.x-dev" "drupal/social_auth_google:2.x-dev"
```

But now composer throws up faults no matter what I do. I tried removing all the "social" entries from `composer.json` but here are the errors I get instead;

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/title_field_for_manage_display ^1.0, found drupal/title_field_for_manage_display[1.0.0, ..., 1.12.0] but the package is fixed to 2.0.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
  Problem 2
    - drupal/social_auth_google[2.0.0, ..., 2.1.0] require drupal/social_auth ^2.0 -> drupal/social_auth is fixed to 2.x-dev (lock file version) by a partial update but that version is rejected by your minimum-stability. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/social_auth_google ^2.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/social_auth_google[2.0.0, 2.1.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

Here's my `composer.json` ;

```
{
"name": "drupal/recommended-project",
"description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with a relocated document root",
"type": "project",
"license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
"homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
"support": {
    "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
    "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    }
],
"require": {
    "composer/installers": "^1.9",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.1",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.1",
    "drupal/title_field_for_manage_display": "^1.0"
},
"conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true,
"config": {
    "sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
    "drupal-scaffold": {
        "locations": {
            "web-root": "web/"
        }
    },
    "installer-paths": {
        "web/core": [
            "type:drupal-core"
        ],
        "web/libraries/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-library"
        ],
        "web/modules/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-theme"
        ],
        "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-drush"
        ],
        "web/modules/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-module"
        ],
        "web/profiles/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-profile"
        ],
        "web/themes/custom/{$name}": [
            "type:drupal-custom-theme"
        ]
    },
    "drupal-core-project-message": {
        "include-keys": [
            "homepage",
            "support"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/recommended-project template!          </>",
            "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
            "",
            "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
            "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
            "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
            "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
            "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
            "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
            "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
            "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
        ]
    }
}
```

}

How can I fix composer?

Comment: Okay, and did you try `composer require "drupal/social_auth_google:^2.0" -W` then and is the outcome okay for you (potential upgrades, downgrades and removals to lockked packages)? And why not just `composer require drupal/social_auth_google`? For Composer questions it's also always a good idea to include your current composer.json

Comment: Yes, I tried both of those. I've just added the composer.json too.

Comment: You need to update `title_field_for_manage_display`. `"drupal/title_field_for_manage_display": "^1.0"` isn't ready for Drupal 9. Run `composer require drupal/title_field_for_manage_display drupal/social_auth_google` or alternatively fix the version constraint manually in composer.json.

Comment: I got this error with that command;  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires drupal/social_auth_google ^2.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/social_auth_google[2.1.0].
    - drupal/social_auth_google 2.1.0 requires drupal/social_auth ^2.0 -> drupal/social_auth is fixed to 2.x-dev (lock file version) by a partial update but that version is rejected by your minimum-stability. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

Comment: Which version constraint should I fix manually in composer.json ?

Comment: Change `"minimum-stability": "stable",` to `"minimum-stability": "dev",` and rerun `composer require drupal/title_field_for_manage_display drupal/social_auth_google`.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. Can you leave it as an answer so I can choose it as solved?

Comment: Basic Composer. Maybe add an answer yourself if you like. That's fine.